# "Syntax error" while writing OCaml function?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am writing a function in OCaml to raise x to the power of y.
My code is:

```
#let rec pow x y =
if y == 0 then 1 else
if (y mod 2 = 0) then pow x y/2 * pow x y/2 else
x * pow x y/2 * pow x y/2;;
```

When I try to execute it, I get an error for syntax in line one, but it doesn't tell me what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrote the code, did you type the `#`? The `#` is just a character that the OCaml REPL outputs to prompt for input; it is not part of the code. You should not type it.

Here are some other errors that you should fix:

- `==` is physical equality in OCaml. `=` is structural equality. Although both work the same for unboxed types (such as `int`), it's better practice to do `y = 0`. Note that you use `=`, the recommended equality, in the expression `y mod 2 = 0`.
- You need parentheses around `y/2`. `pow x y/2` parses as `(pow x y) / 2`, but you want `pow x (y / 2)`.